# PHP ZipArchive, play FLAC audio file which is inside a zip archive without extraction

Tags: javascript, php, blob, html5-audio, flac

It is about the following:

I like to play an audio file which is inside a zip archive without extraction.

This is my current approach:

```
<?
$z = new ZipArchive();
if ($z->open(dirname(__FILE__) . '/archiv.zip')) {
    $string = $z->getFromName("Part.flac");
}

?>

<audio src="?????" controls></audio>
```

The reading part works, but `getFromName` returns a string, the question is now how to convert the string back to it's 'binary flac format', so that the audio element can play it.

Any other better approach?

Comment: you can't do anything with any file inside a zip, you always have to extract it (even if just into memory).

Comment: _"the question is now how to convert the string back to it's 'binary flac format', so that the audio element can play it"_ - the keyword here would be _Data URI_; but that is probably a rather bad idea in a case like this, because of the amount of data. A dedicated script as source for the audio element, that then reads the flac data from the zip file and passes it on to the client, would make more sense.

Comment: Thank you very much, OK I'd rather extract the files then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do anything with any file inside a zip, you always have to extract it (even if just into memory).